# Calling a NSBaseURLDocumentOption for NSMutableAttributedString IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablestring

I'm using a NSMutableAttributedString to pull in business descriptions that are in html and css scripting. Although I'm able to manipulate the font color, style, and ext the internal images arent showing up. It works for `<img alt='' src='http://i189.photobucket.com/albums/z189/txmom3x/Crabby%20Daddy/crabbydrinks.jpg' style='height:148px; width:222px' />`

but not this

```
<img alt='' src='/cnt/files/This%20is%20the%20one/pinterest.png' style='height:28px; width:28px' />
```

The URL for the image is presumably relative to the URL of the page the HTML is considered to come from. By the time you create the attributed string from the HTML, it's no longer associated with a URL, so the system can't construct an absolute URL for the image and can't find it. How can I specify the base URL? I heard you could use something like NSBaseURLDocumentOption but that only works for OS X

```
// Create NSMutableAttributedString
                var data: NSData = busDescriptio.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                var foo: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
                    options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                documentAttributes:nil,
                error:nil)!
                var paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
                foo.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Arial", size:12)!, range:NSMakeRange(0, foo.length))
                foo.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length: foo.length))
                foo.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.clearColor(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: foo.length))
                foo.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraph, range:NSMakeRange(0, foo.length))
```

Comment: You need to specify the base url

Comment: Hey! where do I do that at?

Comment: <head>
 <base href="h t t p ://www.yourDomain.com/" />

Comment: I see what you are saying the only thing is that busDescriptio is a string that I get from a database so its different everytime. Would I be able to insert that for every different file that comes up? Like how does that work? Also I looked into something different that may be able to help for what I'm trying to do what do you think? http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app